# Product of all reduced residues in relation with the function $\mu$: $\prod_{1\leq a\leq n,(a,n)=1}a=n^{\varphi(n)}\prod_{d|n}(d!/d^d)^{\mu(n/d)}$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-inversion

We know that for any arithmetic function $f$ the Mobius inversion formula gives its inversion. Hence
$$
F(n)=\prod_{d|n}f(d)\implies f(n)=\prod_{d|n}
F(n/d)^{\mu(d)}.$$
The above statement can be proven by taking logarithm on both sides. Using this result, I think showing the result as stated in the title
$$
\prod_{1\leq a\leq n,(a,n)=1}a=n^{\varphi(n)}\prod_{d|n}\left(\frac{d!}{d^d}\right)^{\mu(n/d)}
$$
is equivalent to showing
$$
\frac{n!}{n^n}=\prod_{d|n}\prod_{1\leq a\leq d, (a,d)=1}\frac{a}{d}.
$$
However, I cannot proceed from here efficiently. Is this the right track to the solution and is there any hints/key observations that I am missing?

Comment: $\prod_{a\le n, \gcd(a,n)=1} a = 
\prod_{a\le n} a^{\sum_{d|n,d|a} \mu(d)}$